# Serialize a binary tree?

Tags: c, serialization, binary-tree

I have a binary tree represented with the following structure:

```
typedef struct _TREENODE
{
     int data;
     struct tree_node *left;
     struct tree_node *right;
} TREENODE;
```

I'm trying to serialize it for file storage, but I've hit a wall with how to go about this. All I have so far is the file header:

```
typedef struct _TREEFILEHEADER
{
     short magic; // Identifies the file as a binary tree file
     int size;    // Number of nodes in the tree
} TREEFILEHEADER;
```

What is a good strategy for actually storing the data in the tree?

Comment: Typically a pre-order traversal. This makes it relatively easy to re-construct the tree, because you read the data in the order you're going to create nodes in the tree, and you can figure out where in the tree each item needs to go based on a fairly small number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to serialize it is to convert the tree into an array, and have the "pointers" be indexes into the array. Then you can just write the array as-is to a file, preferably in a text format to keep it portable.

When reading the file, you read it into the array, and then deserialize the array into the proper tree.